# Bridge networking is not working in virtual box 4.2.8 with ubuntu 12.04 host and ubuntu 11.10 guest

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, virtualization

Very good article but there is a problem for me.
I am using virtual box 4.2.8 with ubuntu 12.04 host and ubuntu 11.10 guest. I am unable to setup bridge networking beetween host and guest. here i am pasting configuration of interfaces.
Configuration on Ubunutu12.04 host

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.56.22
netmask 255.255.255.0   
broadcast 192.168.56.255
gateway 192.168.56.1
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_maxwait 0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

And for ubuntu 11.10 guest, i am selected bridged adapter and under name i selected eth0 interface.
And configuration of guest ethernet interface is

```
auto eth2
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.56.23
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255
gateway 192.168.56.1
```

But it is not working when i ping it just says destination host unreachable. Please help

Comment: The bridged adapter name eth0 that you selected in the VM settings is the host's eth0. The guest might have a different interface name. Use ifconfig to figure that out.